# Custom Powershell Host Invoke external program without console window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm writing an embedded powershell host in C# (windows application), and if there is an external program called in the pipeline the console window flashes as it's executed. Ping and netstat are examples of this as shown in the following code snippet

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {

        PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-Content test.txt; ls; ping www.google.com");

        PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

        # ...more code here to print output etc

    }
```

Once the ping command is reached in the pipeline a console window will popup execute the command and return results. I would like to do this without the console window showing. I've searched and found examples of how to deal with this by starting a process for external commands and redirecting output.

I can do that of course, but then how would I test if a command in the pipeline is a call to an external program?

I would really like to be able to handle this generically if possible; meaning that I don't want to test for specific programs (e.g. ping, netstat, net) if I don't have to. The native powershell.exe does this so it's somehow possible.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use built-in methods for these things? Like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ?

Comment: No that would work assuming there are methods for all the usual windows utilities. Is that the case? Also, if a user enters "netstat" on the embedded command line the PowershellInstance automatically just calls the netstat.exe? How would I tell it otherwise without parsing every command and then checking to see if it has built-in method alternative. I would like to have the same functionality in my application as the native powershell.exe if possible.

Comment: How about creating the script and running it through the command line using `Process.Start`, and setting it to not create a window? You can redirect standard input/output streams back to the application and read it with standard stream objects.

Comment: Do you have an example? I've see examples like showm here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/09/28/createnowindow.aspx, but that doesn't seem to take into account an embedded powershell host implementation.

Comment: MSDN has a good example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I appreciate it, but it doesn't really answer my question about integrating with an embedded powershell host. I'm not just calling powershell.exe. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is expected behavior of invoking console commands. In Windows 7 and above conhost.exe is responsible for handling calls to console programs. In this case, ping and netstat trigger an instance of conhost to be created, it handles the request, returns the results, and then remains open. conhost.exe starting up is what is causing the console flash I'm seeing. The fact that it remains open is why I was only seeing the console window flash once. Once conhost is connected to the calling process all subsequent console commands are handled by that same instance.

I'm marking this as an answer because a new question should be created to address conhost specifically.

Source. Windows Internals Part 1